# How to make a recursive function type safe?

Tags: typescript, recursion, promise

I have a component where the user can drag & drop files or folders onto it and the my code is doing something with that info.

Now I got a recursive method which is traversing a folder for files and other folders which could also have other folders with files in it and so on (I guess you get the idea). In the end I would like to have all the files which were dropped by the user.

Currently I got this method:

```
private traverseDirectory(entry: FileSystemDirectoryEntry): Promise<FileSystemEntry[]> {
    const reader = entry.createReader();
    return new Promise<FileSystemEntry[]>(resolveDirectory => {
      const iterationAttempts: Promise<FileSystemEntry>[] = [];
      const errorHandler = () => {
        logger.error('Error occurred while traversing directory.');
      };

      const readEntries = () => {
        reader.readEntries((batchEntries: FileSystemEntry[]) => {
          if (!batchEntries.length) {
            resolveDirectory(Promise.all(iterationAttempts));
          } else {
            batchEntries.forEach((batchEntry: FileSystemEntry) => {
              if (batchEntry.isDirectory) {
                iterationAttempts.push(
                  this.traverseDirectory(batchEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry) as any,
                );
              } else {
                iterationAttempts.push(Promise.resolve(batchEntry));
              }
            });
            readEntries();
          }
        }, errorHandler);
      };
      readEntries();
    });
  }
```

Now I would like to get rid of the " as any " part in the line after the isDirectory() condition.

I tried for several hours to come up with something but couldn't get it done and would appreciate some help.

Any advice on how to make the code maybe more readable or cleaner is very welcome as I am rather new to Angular and would like to improve my knowledge.

Thank you :)

Comment: What kind of files?

Comment: The problem on the `any` line seems to be that `traverseDirectory` returns an array but you want to push that as a single element on another array.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and clearly see the issue you’re talking about. Right now it’s an excerpt of something and most of the types and values are undeclared. Instead of an excerpt, it would be helpful if you’d produce a standalone and self-contained example with all the pieces needed (and nothing unneeded) to show the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! [Promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) only the `readEntries` method itself, then use promise chaining or even better clean `async`/`await`:

```
private async traverseDirectory(directory: FileSystemDirectoryEntry): Promise<FileSystemFileEntry[]> {
  const reader = entry.createReader();
  const dirEntries = await new Promise<FileSystemEntry[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.readEntries(resolve, reject);
  });

  const result: FileSystemFileEntry[] = [];
  for (const entry of dirEntries) {
    if (entry.isDirectory) {
      result.push(...await this.traverseDirectory(entry));
    } else if (entry.isFile) {
      result.push(entry);
    } else {
      console.warn(`Ignoring unsupported entry at ${entry.fullPath}`);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer as it solves my problem. I guess I was overthinking the issue a lot. Thank you as well for the antipattern info! Take care

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your function is returning `Promise<FileSystemEntry[]>` (promise that returns a list of file entries). In contrast, a list that you are attempting to add this promise has a different type signature `Promise<FileSystemEntry>[]` (list of promises) because the type is different you have to cast it to any. Adjust the type of your list.